# [linux find cmd]: limit the find command to search directories matching a given word or regex

Tags: linux, find

Can I limit the find command to search directories matching a given regex only?

I looked at

```
$ man find
```

but couldn't find any --include-directories option.

Using RHEL GNU/Linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can try is :

```
find . ! \( -name . -o -regex ".*/dir" \) -prune -name file
```

The problem for this solution is you have to include starting directory (. in this case)

-prune means to exclude all directories except `.` or `.*/dir`